# printing a sentence on screen

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I need to print a full sentence on screen with the `ah`, 09h technique. I don't now why it doesn't show up on screen.

```
message db 'game over, to play again press y$'
PROC GAMEOVER
push dx
    call cleanscreen
    mov dx, offset message
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    mov ah,0
    int 16h
    cmp al, 'y'
    jne line
        CALL STARTGAME
    line:
    pop dx
RET 
ENDP GAMEOVER

proc cleanscreen ; cleans the screen
    push cx
    push bx
    mov cx,4000d
    mov bx,0
    clean:
        mov [byte ptr es:bx],0
        inc bx
    loop clean
    pop bx
    pop cx
    ret
endp cleanscreen
```

Comment: Have you set the segment register `ds` correctly?

Comment: Is the cursor at the far right hand side of the screen?  (Or does AH=9 line-wrap?)  In your previous question, [Why my code run procs when I don't want it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70052306), you were setting `ds` correctly I think, unless your message is really mixed in with code rather than data.  In that case, its offset within the code section wouldn't be correct relative to `ds`, since DS and CS bases can be different in a .exe.  (A .com is simpler.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the *cleanscreen* proc:

> ```
> proc cleanscreen ; cleans the screen
>  push cx
>  push bx
>  mov cx,4000d
>  mov bx,0
> clean:  mov [byte  ptr es:bx],0
>  inc bx
>  loop clean
>  pop bx
>  pop cx
>  ret
> endp cleanscreen
> ```

The screen is setup for the 80x25 16-color text mode. When you clear the screen storing all zeroes in it, it means that all the character cells get filled with ASCII code 0 (which is a space character) and attribute 00h (which is BlackOnBlack). The important thing here is that the DOS.PrintString function 09h does not care about the attributes already present on the screen, and neither does it output any new color information. Thus the characters of your text get written to screen fine but **you don't get to see any of it because of the *black* foreground color and the *black* background color**.

Write the proc this way:

```
proc cleanscreen ; cleans the screen
    push ax
    push cx
    push di
    mov  ax, 0720h  ; WhiteOnBlack space character
    mov  cx, 2000   ; 80*25
    xor  di, di
    rep  stosw      ; write CX words starting at [es:di] 
    pop  di
    pop  cx
    pop  ax
    ret
endp cleanscreen
```

Comment: your solution gave me an idea, instead of inc bx I changed it to add bx,2 and it works now.  The information about ah,9 and color attribute works was eyes opening. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget that `proc cleanscreen` expects `ES=B800h`.  The screen is also cleared whenever [videomode is reset](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm) :  `MOV AX,0003` `INT 10h`.