# how to change the color attribute to white-on- black

Tags: assembly, x86, screen

I want to use ah, 9h to write a message on screen. but when I clean the screen, the text attribute changes the text to be black-on-black. To which value I should change the clean screen proc. so the text will be visible? thanks.

```
DATASEG
message db 'GAME OVER$'
```

the cleanscreen proc. :

```
    push cx bx
    mov cx,2000d
    mov bx,0
    clean:
        mov [WORD ptr es:bx],00 ; the value that should be changed
        add bx, 2
    loop clean
    pop cx bx
    ret
endp cleanscreen
```

the calling in the "main" :

```
    call cleanscreen
    mov dx, offset message
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
```

Comment: Tha foreground color is in bits 8-11, isn't it? So make your loop store `0F00h` instead of `00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### An error on register preservation

> ```
> push cx bx
> ...
> pop cx bx
> ret
> ```

The stack is a LIFO structure (LastInFirstOut); What goes on the stack last, must come off first. In your code the `BX` register got pushed last, therefore it has to come off first using code like `pop bx cx`.
If the stack is something that you're not comfortable with yet, I would suggest using the other way of writing this:

```
push cx
push bx
...
pop  bx
pop  cx
ret
```

### Using character attributes

The textscreen that you use, stores 3 pieces of information for every character that it displays.
For each word in the video memory will the low byte contain the **A**SCII code of the character, and will the high byte register the character's **f**oreground color in the low nibble and the character's **b**ackground color in the high nibble.

```
bbbbffffAAAAAAAAh
```

An instruction like `mov [WORD ptr es:bx],00` that uses the `WORD` tag, will clear all 3 pieces of information, producing a BlackOnBlack space character. Please note that writing `00` does in no way mean **byte** and nor does writing `0000` mean **word**. The size of the operation is defined by the mention of `byte ptr` or `word ptr`.

In a comment of yours beneath my answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70052944/printing-a-sentence-on-screen) you suggested yourself a way to clean the screen without touching the color attributes:

```
  xor  bx, bx
clean:
  mov  [BYTE ptr es:bx],00  ; Only the ASCII field
  add  bx, 2
  loop clean
```

In order to change the colors of the screen to WhiteOnBlack (07h) and keeping the existing text, we can use:

```
  mov  bx, 1
clean:
  mov  [BYTE ptr es:bx], 07h  ; Only the attribute field
  add  bx, 2
  loop clean
```

And to restore the screen completely to WhiteOnBlack spaces (0720h), use:

```
  xor  bx, bx
clean:
  mov  [WORD ptr es:bx], 0720h  ; ASCII & attribute fields
  add  bx, 2
  loop clean
```

For BrightWhiteOnBlack use 0F20h.

Answer (score 0):

where you used mov word ptr es:[bx], 0 it's better use 0f20h ... 0F means white on black and 20h is a space character